# Will devise let me use multiple ORM in a single project ? if yes how would I do that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, devise

I have a project where I am using both mongoDB and postgressql.
one part of the project uses mongoDB, and is a independent Rails::Engine. has it's own devise model.

now in the root project in which this engine is mounted as a gem. and uses postgresql. Is there a way in which I can have one more devise model which talks to postgresql ?